# What is actually loaded here and different hexdump outputs on util-linux hexdump and on cutter and ghidra's hexdump

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, linux, radare2, elf

I was trying to understand what segment of file gets loaded by fourth LOAD header on phdr array.
 First 6 headers are shown below from readelf

```
 Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x0000000000000268 0x0000000000000268  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000000002a8
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 //file portion till .text
                 0x00000000000006c0 0x00000000000006c0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 //.text
                 0x00000000000003c5 0x00000000000003c5  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 //.rodata,.eh_frame_hdr,.eh_frame
                 0x0000000000000170 0x0000000000000170  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x0000000000003de8
                 0x0000000000000270 0x00000000000002d8  RW     0x1000
```

that memory range between offset and filesiz is completely absent in ghidra and cutter disassembly and is filled with "ff" and is shown as invalid in cutter hexdump.
however, when I use hexdump on my terminal, it is not filled with 'ff' as shown by cutter

```
00002df0  e0 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e10  00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e20  d8 11 00 00 00 00 00 00  19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e30  e8 3d 00 00 00 00 00 00  1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.=..............|
00002e40  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  1a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e50  f0 3d 00 00 00 00 00 00  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.=..............|
00002e60  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f5 fe ff 6f 00 00 00 00  |...........o....|
00002e70  08 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e80  d0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002e90  28 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(...............|
00002ea0  84 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002eb0  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002ec0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002ed0  00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.@..............|
00002ee0  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002ef0  07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002f00  48 05 00 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |H...............|
00002f10  88 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002f20  c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002f30  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  fb ff ff 6f 00 00 00 00  |...........o....|

-->disassembly from cutter
            0x00002de8      invalid
            0x00002de9      invalid
            0x00002dea      invalid
            0x00002deb      invalid
            0x00002dec      invalid
            0x00002ded      invalid
            :and this continues till 0x00003de7
```

why the difference?
what is actually getting loaded by the fourth LOAD ?

The program I'm disassembling is a simple hello world program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

compiled with 
gcc version 9.1.0 (GCC)

Answer (score 1):

So I'm still looking for a better understanding but I found that the GNU_RELRO points from 0x03de8-0x04000, which tells me that this is somehow connected to dynamic relocation sections, and running objdump -R gives me this

```
DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000003de8 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000001130
0000000000003df0 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x00000000000010e0
0000000000004028 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000004028
0000000000003fd8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000003fe0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000003fe8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __gmon_start__
0000000000003ff0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000003ff8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004018 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  printf@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

still don't have a clear understanding so I cant mark this question as solved and I dont know why hexdump on both tools differ as indicated in the question.